# how to get an svn revision number of a project?

Tags: svn

SVN provides the possibility to get the revision number of a single file with the property $Revision$. This is fine for a single file. I'm using it in a C++ project that consists of several files in a single folder. Is there a similar way to get one single revision number of the complete project ?
In my understanding this should be the highest version number of all the files in the project folder.

I already know that it is possible to get the latest revision number using a bash script but I'd like to avoid this.

Comment: not sure what you are looking for .... you want the version number of the folder, or all the versions for all the files in the folder ?

Comment: I edited my question to describe my requirement a bit more precisely

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have Global Revision Number per repository, you can use different methods

- Instead of bash-script just run `svnversion` (program is part of SVN on any platform) inside working Copy and intercept output
- For more complex requests you can use [subwcrev](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html) (part of TortoiseSVN on Windows) or it's Linux brother [svnrev](http://www.compuphase.com/svnrev.htm) (slightly outdated, noreleases from 27 February 2012, may not work with SVN 1.8 Working Copies) at build-stage - store and version "template-file", generate and use "real-file" on demand

Comment: I wanted to avoid platform dependent scripting because we are developing software for QNX under Linux and Windows machines. But I already suspected that there is no simple "magic" solution...